# call a method with a concatenated string

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, runtime, call

In Java I want to call a method in a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
 myMethod.get + Integer.toString(i)(theValue);
}
```

where the method called is named myMethod.get1, myMethod.get2, myMethod.get3 ...

Can this be done?

Comment: It is possible using reflection - but why is it you need to do this? What's the underlying requirement? There may be much better solutions to your problem than this.

Answer (score 6):

In principle this is possible through reflection. However, a question like this is often a symptom that your program is badly designed. Most likely you would be much better off storing your data in a data structure such as a `List` or an array, which allows you to get values out of it by index, or maybe a `Map`.

Comment: +1: Reflection shouldn't be the solution to a badly designed application.

Answer (score 1):

encapsulate your processing logic like this

```
interface Worker {

    void doWork(Object param);
}

class Test {

    private HashMap<Integer, Worker> map = new HashMap<Integer, Worker>();

    public Test() {
        map.put(1, new Worker() {

            @Override
            public void doWork(Object param) {
                // do something for 1
            }
        });
        map.put(2, new Worker() {

            @Override
            public void doWork(Object param) {
                // do something for 2 
            }
        });

    }


    public void invoke(int id, Object param){
        map.get(id).doWork(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is generally a good idea, but you can use the reflection API:
[Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Class.html) has a method called getMethod, which takes a string argument, the method's name (also some optional arguments for the parameter types), then you can call it by calling `invoke` on it.

Answer (score 0):

[look at Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use reflection API for this. See java.lang.reflect.Method class and use its invoke method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instead of hitting different methods, which i beleive you are doing for certain set of operations, you should create class for each functionality. All these classes should be extending a common class or better will be to implement an interface. This interface can have a method get() which will be implemented in each of the clases.

Now you need to create an array/list of references of these objects. And call the get() method of each of these classes in the for loop.

Of course you can use reflection otherwise.